# pipelines fail with custom docker image

Tags: git, bash, shell, docker, bitbucket

I have a custom docker image on docker hub: `salmantariq/node_mysql`. It has MySQL server installed on it and node via nvm. I get the following error. I am sure I am missing something here but don't know what.

```
{
bash: cannot set terminal process group (9): Not a ttybash: no job control in this shell+ umask 000+ git clone --branch="user-login-error-fix" --depth 50 https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/diligensoftware/web.git $BUILD_DIR ; git reset --hard ed570209d7a4a1d7b29fe09d9dd7909ed42ed65e ; git remote set-url origin https://x-token-auth:{access_token}@bitbucket.org/diligensoftware/web.gitCloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'...HEAD is now at ed57020 configuring test+ chmod 777 $BUILD_DIRbash: cannot set terminal process group (9): Inappropriate ioctl for devicebash: no job control in this shell
}
```

Comment: You get the error while doing what? Where is your Dockerfile?

Comment: error occurs during build in bitbucket pipeline